# node.js and nodemailer how to save attachments

Tags: node.js, pdf

I am using node version 7.10.0 with:

pdf2json    version 1.1.7
mail parser version 2.0.5
smtp-server version 3.0.1

I have received an email with a PDF attachment and I want to parse the PDF using pdf2json without saving the PDF to disk, I have the byte array from the email attachment.  How can I parse this directly to the module?

I thought I could do this:

```
    const pdfParser     = require("pdf2json");

    let objPDF = new pdfParser();
    objPDF.parseBuffer(arybytContent);
```

Where 'arybytContent' is the content from the mail attachment:

```
    arybytContent = objAttachment["content"]["data"];
```

Looking at objPDF using Chrome, it doesn't look like the content has been parsed correctly, is the content encoded in some way?

I've tried searching online for help, but couldn't find anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution in the end was to convert the array to a Buffer, attempting to write an array using available fs methods would result in a comma delimited set of values.  A buffer is written as binary data.